# Reuse application.yml for tests

Tags: spring-boot

in Spring Boot there are usually two `application.yml` files, in `src/main/java/resources` and `src/test/java/resources`. The first one will be used in when the program is run, the second one when the tests are run.

We had some errors in the past that were introduced by adding something in the main yml file but weren't manually copied over to the test yml. Therefore the tests still worked (since they worked on the old yml) but the main application would not. This is unlikely but still the fact you need to manually sync those doesn't feel good to me.

So what I would like to do is only to have the main `application.yml` with an additional test profile, that would load the test overrides for the unit tests.

I had two angles on how to achieve this:

1. Overriding the classloader to load the main yml in the the tests in a `@Configuration` or try to additionally load the main yml. This didn't work since `src/main/java/resources` is not on the classpath when the tests are run. Careful, you could load the file, this works when the tests are run from source, but doesn't if the application is packaged in a jar.
2. A gradle task that runs before the tests and copies the main yml to the test resources. This works, but I don't like it since it is intransparent.

Is there any canonical way to do this or is there any reason of why this is a stupid idea in the first place and shouldn't be done? For me it would seem, because Spring works so well with profiles, that a single `application.yml` with different profiles for `dev`, `test`, `e2e`, ... would be the sensible default since it is a single point of truth.

Answer (score -1):

If you put your application.yml under `src/test/resources/config/` , and not in `src/main/resources/`, your tests using @SpringBootTest should have access by default to the values set in application.yml from `src/main/resources/`

And you should only have to override test-specific properties within ... `/config/application.yml`

[Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) is documented the possible config subdirectory usage

Comment: This is simply not correct :)

Comment: works for me, so please explain

Comment: @EugenMayer you possibly left a application.yml under test/resources